# MySQL is stuck in sorting state

Tags: mysql

Lately i have an issue with my website, the mysql load reaches 800% and most of the queries are stuck in "Sorting Result" set.

The issue is that i've made a test. Same query with 1 result set, with sorting was taking 9,8 seconds and without it takes 0.02 seconds. The query contains where conditions and group by.

The sql is optimized, the search is made in indexed fields and everything went fine until couple of days ago. No traffic spike, no code change, nothing.

Did you had this issue in the past or do you have any idea how can i fix it?

Thanks

Edit:
The explain of the query:

```
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: m
         type: range
possible_keys: posterid_to_idx,to,poster_id
          key: posterid_to_idx
      key_len: 8
          ref: NULL
         rows: 6
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
```

Again, same query worked fine couple of days ago.

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `body` longtext NOT NULL,
  `poster_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `poster_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `folder` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `posterid_to_idx` (`poster_id`,`to`),
  KEY `to` (`to`),
  KEY `poster_id` (`poster_id`),
  KEY `msg` (`id`,`poster_id`,`to`),
  KEY `added` (`added`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37548617 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS m.body, m.id,  m.poster_id, m.poster_name, m.to, m.added, m.picture, m.folder
FROM messages m
WHERE  ((m.poster_id = '1885585' OR m.poster_id = '1886341') 
      AND (m.to = '1886341' OR m.to = '1885585'))                 
ORDER BY m.id DESC                 LIMIT 0, 10
```

Top Output:

```
CPU:  6.0% user,  0.0% nice, 38.8% system,  0.2% interrupt, 55.0% idle
Mem: 11G Active, 1400M Inact, 5451M Wired, 87M Cache, 4923M Buf, 29G Free
Swap: 8000M Total, 8000M Free
```

Comment: Maybe the index you sorted on just outgrew the available cache space?

Comment: what version of mysql?  MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: @EricPetroelje - Version 5.5.32-log Source distribution and table InnoDB
JoachimIsaksson - I have no idea how to check that :(

Comment: what is the explain of the query saying ?

Comment: @user1281385 - Added in the post

Comment: Seeing this concerns me: `Using filesort`.  What are you ordering the results by, and are you sure there's an index on that field?

Comment: @EricPetroelje  am using 2 fields to search and both are in index (KEY `posterid_to_idx` (`poster_id`,`to`)) and the sorting is made on the primary key.

Comment: @EricPetroelje and keepwalking - The indexes are not used. `Using filesort` actually means the results are sorted without using an index. It has nothing to do with files. See [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/).

Comment: It is not using your indexes when sorting because of `type=range`, show us your query and table structure.

Comment: @ludesign Please check - btw, this happens to all queries, not this one. almost all queries are stuck in that state.

Comment: The cache is being hit, And possibly your quite high on RAM usage meaning its being swapped ? Need more info from the mysql server

Comment: @user1281385 - i will post top output of the server.

Comment: just a suggestion: You can create a temp table with your unsorted result, add indexes to the temp table (if needed) and then select the temp table with the sort. That 'divide and conquer' strategy has helped me many times

Comment: @keepwalking - I think the problem is caused by using `id` which is not part of the `posterid_to_idx` index used for filtering in `WHERE` and is causing MySQL to not use indexes on sorting. Let me verify.

Comment: @ludesign - nope, that is not it :(

Comment: @keepwalking - Yes, unfortunately, MySQL won't use it. Well I tried a lot of things to optimize the query and the ordering with no success - even tried with `UNION ALL` :D. I am sorry but I couldn't do much more to help you. Half an year ago we had to implement messaging for a dating service and we decided to go with a very optimized table design, I can tell you more if you are interested.

Comment: @ludesign don't think the query is the issue. i repeat, it worked perfect couple of days ago ... and all queries have started having this issue, not just this one. All of them are blocked in Sorting ... so something happened with the sorting mechanicasm

Comment: @keepwalking - Yes I've read that. Have you tried to restart MySQL? From `top` I can see you have enough free RAM. Could it be MySQL Query Cache? Check your disk space. Try `FLUSH TABLES` - should fix it if its Query Cache related. Can you try this `SHOW PROFILES;` then run `SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY X;` where `X` is the `ID` of the query you want to examine (look at `Query_ID ` column). I am very out of ideas of what might be causing this issue. Hope we'll hunt it down soon or later. If you manage to resolve it, I won't mind to let us know what the issue was. :)

Comment: Could you show the result from `show variables like 'innodb_buffer%';`?

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but once I had problems on selecting data and the solution was to rebuild table and indexes.  Try `repair table TABLE_NAME` for all the used tables

Comment: Since this table is InnoDB, it won't use the MyISAM key buffer anyway - InnoDB has its own buffer, you should make sure `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is high enough to hold the index in RAM (your 29G free memory suggests you could increase the buffer pool size a lot).  You also have ~37 million rows in your messages table, judging by the auto_increment value.  It may be time to archive the older messages, which will decrease the index size.  Also `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is often a performance killer.

Comment: Btw, you can't do a `range` query *and* have the query use an index for sorting.  The two are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

So after a lot of tryouts with my.cnf i fixed the issue by:

1. Decreasing query cache value
2. Decreasing key buffer value
3. Decreasing tmp table value
4. Disabled performance schema

I've just tested various configurations and know on full traffic (about 6k people online) my mysql stays on 50% load which is pretty awsome. No sql or modifications were made, just innodb tweaking.

Not really sure if this is an answer for someone with the  same issue but its my answer at least.

My.cnf

```
query_cache_limit=128M
query_cache_size=128M
query_cache_type=1
key_buffer_size=128M
tmp_table_size=64M
performance_schema=off
```